# plot this in ggplot. Controlling y axis line within a range

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis

This is using base, where I can control the x and y axis range, where exactly the line should be drawn.

```
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp, ylim = c(0, 400), xlim = c(0, 50), axes = F, xlab  = 'mpg', ylab = 'hp', pch = 16)
axis(side = 2, at = seq(100, 400, 100))
axis(side = 1, at = seq(10, 30, 10))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp))+geom_point()+
theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 30, 10), limits = c(0, 50))+
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(100, 400, 100), limits = c(0, 400))
```

[image]

How do I add axis line exactly like base plot ? I have tried `scale_y_continuous` and `scale_x_continuous` but it always draws till the end of the plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get there using the `ggthemes` package:

```
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_rangeframe(data = data.frame(mpg = c(10, 30), hp = c(100, 400))) +
  theme_tufte() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 30, 10), limits = c(0, 50))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(100, 400, 100), limits = c(0, 400))
```

[image]

You *can* also draw them manually, if you want:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(
    aes_all(c('x', 'y', 'xend', 'yend')),
    data.frame(x = c(0, 10), xend = c(0, 30), y = c(100, 0), yend = c(400, 0))
  ) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 30, 10), limits = c(0, 50), expand = c(0, 0))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(100, 400, 100), limits = c(0, 400), expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it before (using theme_hc()). But I want to do this with out using ggthemes. Is it possible ?

Comment: I guess you could manually draw the segments when turning of the scale expanding.

Comment: yeah, thats what I had in mind. I will try that. Its surprising that ggplot being this mature has no option for this.

Comment: @PoisonAlien, see edit. For what it is worth, there's a reason ggplot is extendable; I think the conscious choice is to not include a lot of things within the main package itself, but rather keep the package more slim and have add-ons available to the users.

Comment: Makes sense. There are so many add-ons built on top it after all. Thanks for the edit. It works.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to [modify the guides for the x-axis and y-axis](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#truncated-axes) using the `guide_axis_truncated()` function from the `ggh4x` package. If you want to truncate the axes without fine control you can simply pass "axis_truncated" as the value when setting the `x` and `y` guides:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(x = "axis_truncated", y = "axis_truncated") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>